# Django formsets: initializing values for extra fields from list in model formset

Tags: django, forms, django-templates, django-forms

I'm trying to generate a form that mimics a view to make the data easier to enter. It is a scoresheet, where players are the top column headers, with two subheaders for each player. The form currently generates and submits correctly other than having to use the prefab django way of inserting the player.  [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfXjS.jpg) is the current html output of the form template, showing a couple of records and the extra forms (the ------ buttons will be the same for all rows, as reflected in the rows populated by the queryset, and that's what I'd like to initialize in the extras or upon save).

> Form

```
class ScoreForm(ModelForm):
    game = IntegerField(widget=HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Score
        exclude = ['chouette']
        widgets={'score': TextInput(attrs={'size': 6}), 'position': TextInput(attrs={'size':3})}
```

> View

```
def manage_scores(request, chnum=1):    
    chobj = Chouette.objects.get(number = chnum)
    chid = chobj.id
    p_list = Score.objects.filter(chouette = chid).distinct('player').order_by('player').values_list('player', 'player__handle')
    playernum = p_list.count()
    lastgamequery = Score.objects.filter(chouette = chid).latest('game')
    newgame = lastgamequery.game + 1
    ScoreFormSet = modelformset_factory(Score, form = ScoreForm, extra = playernum)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = ScoreFormSet(request.POST)
        for f in formset:
            f.fields['game'].initial=newgame
        if formset.is_valid():
            newscores = formset.save(commit = False)
            for newscore in newscores:
                newscore.chouette = chobj
                newscore.save()
            return redirect('update', chnum=chnum)
    else:
        formset = ScoreFormSet(queryset = Score.objects.filter(chouette = chid).order_by('game', 'player'))
        for f in formset:
            f.fields['game'].initial = newgame
    return render(request, "manage_scores.html", {'player_list' : p_list, 'formset' : formset, 'newgame' : newgame})
```

> And template:

```
    <form method='post' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr><th></th>
            {% for player in player_list %}
            <th class="text-center" colspan="2" >{{ player.1 }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Game</th>
            {% for player in player_list %}
            <th class="text-center">Score</th><th class="text-center">Position</th>
            {% endfor %}
        <tbody>
        {% regroup formset by instance.game as game_list %}
        {% for game in game_list %}
            <tr><td class="text=center">
            {% if game.grouper %}
                {{game.grouper}}
            {% else %}
                {{ newgame }}
            {% endif %}
            </td>
            {% for g in game.list %}
                {{ g.id }}
                {{ g.game }}
                <td class="text-center">{{ g.player }}{{ g.score}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ g.position }}</td>
            {% endfor %}   
        {% endfor %}</tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button" value="Update" />
</form>
```

The {{g.player}} currently in the template allows me to test the form but is obviously not the answer here. The regroup works to put everything in the right place with the queryset data that is passed to the formset but doesn't help me pre-populate the extra forms. Any guidance is much appreciated, and merciless attacks on the rest of the code are also welcome, since I'm new to this and have pretty much cobbled it together with repeated SO searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have solved the problem by excluding the player field from the form and passing the player values into the "newscores" object in the same way the chouette value was passed. Relevant code from view:

```
        if formset.is_valid():
            newscores = formset.save(commit = False)
            pid=0
            for newscore in newscores:
                newscore.chouette = chobj
                if newscore.game == newgame:
                    newscore.player = p_obj[pid]
                pid +=1
                newscore.save()
```